# If $\alpha$ is the nth root of unity , then the value of

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, infinite-product

Given , $\alpha$ is the nth root of unity .
Then , the value of
$$(11-\alpha)(11-\alpha^2)(11-\alpha^3)........(11-\alpha^{n-1})$$
is equal to ...

I tried to use the property : That sum of nth roots of unity is 0 and they form a G.P series.
But I couldn't solve this question,
Suggest some simpler methods or any hint to solve this . Thank you.

Comment: When you write "*the* $n$-th root of unity", presumably you mean "*a* primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roots of $x^n-1=0$ are $1,\alpha, \alpha ^2,...,\alpha ^{n-1}$. So $x^n-1=(x-1)(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha ^2)...(x-\alpha ^{n-1})$. Put $x=11$.

Comment: It should be roots of xⁿ  - 1 =0 .

Comment: Thank you . So it's answer is  $\frac {11^n -1}{10}$,  but can you prove $x^n -1=(x-1)(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)......(x-\alpha^{n-1})$ how ??

Comment: @Sushil See factor theorem.

Comment: Okay , I got it ...